# I am trying to decompress a compressed large file .xml.gz using c sharp

Tags: c#, .net

I am decompressing using gzip stream, I can decompress small files but I can't handle the large files' it is decompressed it to the end of the file and then stopped regarding the error below
The CRC in GZip footer does not match the CRC calculated from the decompressed data
Any help?

the code is

```
public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                return Decompress(ms);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public static byte[] Decompress(Stream inStream)
    {
        try
        {
            inStream.Position = 0;
            using (var stream = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                using (var temp = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        temp.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (read < 1024)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        File.WriteAllBytes("D:/decompressedData.xml", temp.ToArray());
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                    return temp.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I tried deflate and another libraries

Comment: Error message and [mcve] would help a lot ;)

Comment: Show the code, you're using, we can't guess. Edit the question and add the code.

Comment: What are "large files"?. Do note that c# has some issues representing byte arrays larger than 2Gb in size. File streams and gzipStream should be fine, but trying to copy more than 2Gb to a memory stream will likely fail.

Comment: @PoulBak will update it now

Comment: @JonasH the file is only 8 MB

Comment: Compressed, or decompressed? Why are you breaking if you've less read than 1024 bytes (rather than if `Read` returns 0)? Why are you reading into memory at all, rather than writing straight to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make a huge amount of sense as it is. It breaks on receiving less than 1024 bytes for no reason. And you are writing the whole buffer to a file on each loop, but then returning a `MemoryStream`.

You only need a `CopyTo` call, you don't need a loop.

```cs
public static byte[] DecompressToBytes(byte[] data)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    Decompress(new MemoryStream(data), ms);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

public static void DecompressToFile(byte[] data, string filePath)
{
    using var fs = File.OpenWrite(filePath);
    Decompress(new MemoryStream(data), fs);
}

public static void Decompress(Stream inStream, Stream outStream)
{
    using var stream = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, leaveOpen: true);
    stream.CopyTo(outStream);
}
```

If you are still having CRC issues with the above code then your file is corrupted.